# Upgrade from from 15.04 to 15.10 (and possibly to 16.04)

Tags: apt, upgrade, 15.04

I am not able to upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 
(notwithstanding I read analogues answers).

1st: with

```
lsb-release -a
```

I get

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

A window Software updates appears, it starts checking...but, after 15 -20 seconds, this message appears:

```
Failed to download repository...
```

When I restart the version is still 15.04

Any hint?
Thank you
Gianfranco Zosi

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest 16.04?

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: if your end target is 16.04 you'll have to perform 2 sequential upgrades - better fresh install

Comment: @reversiblean: That is what OP's trying to do, but the official upgrade path is through 15.10.

Comment: Which of these commands produced the error message? Did `apt-get update` work out fine?